# Select Distinct model and then count each model

Tags: sql

I'm having a little trouble trying to figure this one out, here is my code as follows:

```
$sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT make FROM A';
```

This just basically selects all the distinct makes in my table from table A, what i would like to do is select the distinct makes (returns 121 makes), I would then like to create a count of each individual model, for instance make A B C has 32 cells with that model. I would like to be able to count it, without having to write excessive amounts of code to count each individual make.

Surely this is possible? Otherwise I'm gonna just be repeating a lot of code.

Comment: `select make, count(*) from a group by make` -- Is this all you're looking for?

Comment: yes that was all i was looking for i was just unsure how to code it, thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT make, COUNT(make) as makeCount
FROM A
GROUP BY make
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = 'SELECT make, Count(*) ModelCount FROM A Group By make';
```